# Deploying chatbot developed in microsoft bot framework to Jabber instant messaging tool

Tags: c#, xmpp, botframework

We have developed the fully functioning chatbot in microsoft bot framework (C# SDKV3). We need to deploy the chatbot to one of the instant messaging tool named Jabber.

After initial analysis we found that there is no direct way of deploying the chatbot to jabber platform. So now either we will have to create a connector between both or we will have to develop the new solution in jabber SDK.

We don't want to go for option 2 as we have solution already ready but we can try creating a connector (also we don't have any experience in creating a connector.

Need suggestions on below 2 points:

1. Any pointers to creating a connector from microsoft bot framework to jabber
2. Is there is any other way of deploying chatbot to jabber?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any other ways. The connector looks like to be the best option. To do so, you could use the directline channel: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directline?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Here is more information on Directline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0